# 2D bounding box collisions with rotation

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

I am currently working on a simple space game for android. My collision detection will be done using rectangular and circular bounding boxes. These bounding boxes need to be able to rotate, so my question is: what is the best to detect a collision between a rotated rectangle and a circle? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are you using an engine or something? The solution could be different, when you're using an existing game-engine instead of building up everything by yourself.

Comment: The naive approach? Sample N points on each side of the rectangle, check if any of the points are within the circle. I am curious as to what the mathematically more efficient method will be.

Comment: Sorry, I am not using an engine, only native code. I am definitely interested in the most efficient method, as it would lead to better collision detection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved my own problem! There are only two cases when a circle intersects a rectangle:
 1. The center of the circle is inside the rectangle
 2. The circle is intersecting one of the sides of the rectangle
So to check for the collision, I first check if the center of the circle is inside the rectangle, after rotating the center of the circle according to the rotation of the rectangle, to simplify my calculations. If the center of the circle is inside the rectangle, I know there is an intersection, and return true.
If the first check returns false, then I check for intersections between each side of the rectangle, and the circle. If there is an intersection I return true. Feel free to comment if anyone wants the code, thanks for the help guys! :)

Answer (score -1):

Generally, bounding boxes just define the **bounds** of an object, (a shape generated by the vertices of an object's max & min's X & Y) - this makes it much simpler to calculate, bounding boxes do not need to rotate as their purpose is met simply as I have explained. If you want to use them for collision detection simply check if the center of the circle plus its radius intersects the rectangle in both axis such as:

```
public boolean boxintersectscircle(BoundingBox box, BoundingCircle circle) {
    if (box.x > circle.centerx+circle.radius) return false;
    if (box.y > circle.centery+circle.radius) return false;
    if (box.x+box.width < circle.centerx-circle.radius) return false;
    if (box.y+box.height < circle.centery-circle.radius) return false;
    return true;
}
```

However bounding boxes aren't accurate - they can leave a lot of unoccupied space so if that's a worry for your game (player frustration), Personally I would implement the separating axis theorem or line/circle detection.

Comment: this would be nice, if the bounding boxes were not rotated. The question refered to rotated bounding boxes

Comment: So would I be better to use a solution that does not involve bounding boxes? I was under the impression that a bounding box is still a bounding box if it rotates...

Comment: I cannot say indefinitely what solution would be the best for you as I don't know about your game (i'm thinking along the lines of the arcade game 'asteroids') but if you want flawless collision detection, I recommend the separating axis theorem.